# omniauth auth/failure message=invalid_credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, linkedin-api

I am using omiauth with ROR and i get the following error,

omniauth auth/failure message=invalid_credentials,

I am able to connect with linkedin, i am asked for user credentials after giving everything the page redirect is happening and i get the above error.

Here is my callback:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
        def create
          auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
          session[:user_id] = user.id
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
        end

        def destroy
          session[:user_id] = nil
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed out!"
        end
end
```

and the routes.rb is

```
Lovelinkedin::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "users#index" 

  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
  match "/auth/failure" => "users#index"
  match "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :signout

end
```

and my omniauth.rb is

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, 'xxxxx', 'ffffffff'
end
```

Please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: i am a new guy to ROR which also one of the reason i could not fix it also it would be helpful if some of you can help me "How to get values from request and response in ROR"

Comment: Which version of omniauth are you using?  The 1.0 release made some vast changes in the way things worked.  Also, if you are using an older version I would recommend upgrading.

Comment: Post your omniauth configuration file. From what I remember, thta's where credentials are declared.

Comment: @JustinD i have added the omniauth.rb file,

Comment: omniauth version is  omniauth (1.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

What is your OmniAuth.config.full_host equal to in your omniauth.rb file?

if its redirecting to a secure site then it should be something like this:
 "https://#{SITE_BASE}"

else just take off the s if its not a secure site